# LINQ Foreign Key Relationship Naming (Address, Address1, Address2)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

is it possible to change the foreign key relationship object naming of LINQ to SQL generated objects?

For example, I have a `Demo` table which has the fields `ItemMinId, ItemMaxId, ItemExlId` which are all foreign key references to my `Item` table.

LINQ generates now `Demo.Item, Demo.Item2, Demo.Item3` fields which makes it difficult in code to distinguish between the actual items.

How can I change this naming, **outside of the DBML** as I'm usually refreshing the entire model by deleting everything and dragging the updated SQL tables onto the LINQ designer surface.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your name across updates, you have to move it to `partial` classes.

The trick is to declare new properties that simply get/set the generated item.

```
public partial class Demo
{
    public int ItemMinId
    {
        get { return Item; }
        set { Item = value; }
    }

    public int ItemMaxId
    {
        get { return Item2; }
        set { Item2 = value; }
    }

    pubilc int ItemExlId
    {
        get { return Item3; }
        set { Item3 = value; }
    }
}
```

You can change the scope of the generated items from `public` to `internal`, but I imagine that will be overwritten on each update too.

Properties of `Demo` that you declare in a separate, partial class, though, will not be changed.

Comment: I can't test this right now, but I don't feel like this would play well with the actual LINQ to SQL engine which generates the SQL to run on the database...